# Issue with OR statement in Python while making simple dice rolling game

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to Python programming and i have a problem with the or statement in this program. When i run it in PyCharm and input 'roll' it works. But when i use 'yes' it seems not to do anything. 
while input() == ("roll") or input() == ("yes"): This line is the problem. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here. When i use only one command for example roll it works perfectly for as many times as i want to run it.

```
# this is a dice rolling game
import random

min = 1
max = 6
def roll_dice():
    x = random.randint(min, max)
    print(x)

print("Would you like to roll the dice?")


while input() == ("roll") or input() == ("yes"):
    roll_dice()
    print("Would you like to roll the dice again ?")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `input()` twice. Call it once and test for existence in a set using `in`:

```
while input() in {'roll', 'yes'}:
    ...
```

If you're on python2, remember you'll need `raw_input`, not `input`.